# require os, Am i missing somehting?

Tags: lua, require, world-of-warcraft

I come from C-family "mainstream" langages and i'm currently giving a try in Lua .

I made a simple code that check for a user entry and try to open an URL (built with user entry) in the default browser.

Saw the command `os.execute("start "URL")` that failed, saying that "os is undefined".

Well, seemed to be logical. I then researched the reason and discovered the "require" key word (which seems to act as a LoadLibrary or kind).

This is where I'm lost ! 
All forums says *"yeah yeah just add `require os` and it will do"*. But it actually fail !

I obviously suspect that i am missing a "file" or path pointing at that "os" description. And that it's so obvious nobody found useful enough to explain or ask for it.

Can someone explain me **what does require**, in details ? **Which file am i supposed to add** (if i really need to ?).

If someone also have **an online lesson** to advise me, i'll accept it with pleasure. I feel like i'm missing a lot of basics and that's really not a "try to step-up" friendly langage

Comment: Your programming environment deliberately disabled `os` library to restrict accessing files and running external programs.  Otherwise, `require("os")` should work.

Comment: No way to find a work around ? Or another way to launch an URL ? Or a script ? Or any C-like program in the current folder ? Or even a Windows Service ?

Comment: If your environment disabled it, no. To me that's a good thing; if something is forbidden, then it **stays** forbidden, no way around it. But as always with Lua, please tell us what your environment even is. What version of Lua? What software runs it? what's the OS?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff When submitting edits say in the comment field *why* you make the edit *"Comment: Relevant tag added."* isn't very useful to reviewers if it's not clear from the question why it's relevant - we don't see comments or answers and their comments in the review queue

Comment: @Kianii - You are not allowed to open browser page.  But you can open messagebox window with your text, see [docs](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/API_message)

Comment: Thanks ! I'll take a look at that and different API (if the website got one too). I might be able  to make my own interface displaying the website informations. Just wanted to avoid that since i'm new to Lua.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard Lua environment has `os` available without using `require`, so you must be using a non-standard Lua environment.

When Lua is embedded into different software, access to libraries like `os` is usually removed, as it is a security risk. (For example, if you allowed full access to the `os` library to anyone using Lua on a webserver, it would mean that anyone could run random shell commands on that server.)

If your Lua environment has been altered in this way, then there is a good chance that you will never be able to use the `os` library whatever you do.

Comment: According to your explanations, there is about 100% chance that it was disabled since the software we're speaking about is World of Warcraft.
No idea on how i could (legaly if possible)  avoid this issue ?

Comment: @Kianii you can't There's a good reason WoW scripts can't run random shell scripts.

Comment: Sure, that seems logical to me. But I'm not trying to run a "random shell script" that could be illegal or dangerous. Just trying to open browser and launch an URL. This is not in the context of WoW. The final purpose is to enter a slashcommand in the chat with pseudo and server as arguments to get the profile of the player on the website. Seems to be a really basic work so i'm surprised it could be impossible.

Comment: From the games perspective it *is* a random shell script though. If you can open the browser, you can also shut down the computer or upload the home folder to your website. It is sad that this breaks your idea, but it's a good (the only right) design decision. One of the things that make Lua powerful is that you can restrict it. Don't expect every Lua environment to be the same; some can do everything you want, others, like this one, lock you into their domain and don't let you do unrelated things.